# Having problems assigning NULL to MySQL from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, null

Copy and pasted (near enough from PHP admin but still does not like it..

```
$conn->query("UPDATE  `pmuryxvf_shoes`.`Job` SET  `shoe_id` = NULL WHERE  `Job`.`job_id` =".$jobid.";");
```

What im attempting to do is set a row to NULL. Can you see the issue. If I place another value were the NULL is its fine.

One last thing - this row is a foreign key but a NULL value can be updated via PHPMyadmin

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be telling you that your data model defines shoe_id as a NOT NULL column. You cannot, therefore, set it to be NULL.

You could modify the table definition to allow NULL values

```
ALTER TABLE pmuryxvf_shoes
  MODIFY( shoe_id INT NULL )
```

Comment: Yes. Copies/pasted from PHPMyADMIN other than the $jobid bit.